# How to post multiselect option and save in Db using ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post multiselect option and save it in Db. I did try few options but same did not work.

`Client` model class:

```
public string OwnerName { get; set; }

public string UnitNumber { get; set; }

public int AreaId { get; set; }   // This is a foreign key
public string AreaName { get; set; }  // This will display dropdown list
```

Controller action method - I am using FormCollection to collect the AreaId from the view to post in `Client` model class:

```
public ActionResult ClientDeal(Client model, FormCollection formCollection)
{
    string selectedArea = formCollection["AreaId"];
}
```

Here is the view with the field I am having trouble with

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label class="control-label col-md-8 font-weight-bold">Area</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AreaId, Model.Areas, new { @class = "form-control selectpicker select", @multiple = "multiple" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Areas, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

this line is wrong:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AreaId, Model.Areas, new { @class = "form-control selectpicker select", @multiple = "multiple" })
```

You need to bind the dropdown to a collection property, have something like:

```
public int[] AreaIds { get; set; }
```

and bind it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AreaIds,
```

There's no need to set the value `Model.Areas` in the helper declaration, just set in the ViewModel when you return the view:

```
return View(new Client { AreaIds = "what you now have in Model.Areas" }
```

There's no need to use `FormCollection`